# In a YYyyMMDD format date where YY may or may not be correct, how would you correct YY without hardcoding?

Tags: perl, validation, date

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but I'll ask anyway.

We get data from a source we can't control. Those data contains dates in YYyyMMDD. The thing is, the data source has a bug in their system which makes the YY part of the date randomly incorrect so we need to make a workaround for it.

So I thought I'll just append the last six digits of the date to today's YY

```
substr($date_today,0,2).substr($date,-6)
```

But the years in those data are not just for this year, it's also for future years.

so let's say today is 2091-09-07 and this system is still running and then we get a date that is 2102-08-06. Then we also get a date with an incorrect year like 2302-09-04. How should I correct it? What sort of coding solution should I do to workaround these errors?

I'm using Perl btw.

Comment: It's not clear how the date is incorrect. Please provide more information: what exactly do you want to do with the date and when?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the years from your data source aren't more than 50 years in the past or future, the following subroutine can be used to guess the correct year given the current year and the last two digits of the year from your data source:

```
sub guess_year {
    my ($cur_year, $yy) = @_;

    my $cur_yy = $cur_year % 100;
    my $YY     = $cur_year - $cur_yy;

    if ($cur_yy < 50) {
        # Previous century.
        if ($yy >= $cur_yy + 50) { $YY -= 100; }
    }
    else {
        # Next century.
        if ($yy <  $cur_yy - 50) { $YY += 100; }
    }

    return $YY + $yy;
}
```

Here are a couple of test cases:

```
sub test {
    my ($cur_year, $yy) = @_;

    my $guess = guess_year($cur_year, $yy);
    print("cur_year: $cur_year, yy: $yy, guess: $guess\n");
}

test(2016, 15);
test(2016, 17);
test(2016, 60);
test(2016, 70);
test(2080, 79);
test(2080, 81);
test(2080, 10);
test(2080, 40);
```

And the results:

```
cur_year: 2016, yy: 15, guess: 2015
cur_year: 2016, yy: 17, guess: 2017
cur_year: 2016, yy: 60, guess: 2060
cur_year: 2016, yy: 70, guess: 1970
cur_year: 2080, yy: 79, guess: 2079
cur_year: 2080, yy: 81, guess: 2081
cur_year: 2080, yy: 10, guess: 2110
cur_year: 2080, yy: 40, guess: 2040
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is the (numeric) difference between the yy's of the two dates (today's date and your input date). And you need to adjust from today's YY (by +1 or -1) whenever the magnitude of the difference is 50 or greater:

```
$todays_yy = substr($date_today,2,2);
$inputs_yy = substr($date,2,2);

$correct_YY = substr($date_today,0,2) + int(($todays_yy-$inputs_yy)/50);

print $correct_YY . substr($date,-6);
```